# spring-boot datasource profiles w/ application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

***Updated Question based upon feedback:***

I have a spring-boot application that has three databases: H2 for integration testing, and Postgresql for qa & production.   Since spring-boot creates a default datasource for you, I don't have anything defined for my integration tests.  I thought I would use application.properties to define my datasource connection values but I am not certain what is the best way to handle this.

I have two files:

**src/main/resources/application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=production
appName = myProduct
serverPort=9001

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/myDatabase
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.use_sql_comments=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.type=all
spring.jpa.hibernate.disableConnectionTracking=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.default_schema=dental
```

**src/main/resources/application-test.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=test
serverPort=9002

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:~/testdb
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password = 
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver

liquibase.changeLog=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.sql
```

I used to run my tests with with gradle (using "gradle build test") or within IntelliJ.  I updated my gradle file to use:

```
task setTestEnv {
    run { systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", "test" }
}
```

But when I run **gradle clean build setTestEnv test**   I get errors that seem to indicate the test is trying to connect to an actual Postgresql database:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:138)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:32)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:288)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
```

I haven't figured out how to set the default system.property == "test" within IntelliJ yet...

Comment: Why aren't you letting Spring Boot configure  your datasource. Simply put the production one in the `application.properties` then for your tests create an `application-test.properties` file containing the settings for your test database. (Which will override the main ones). Or if you only run your tests from maven/gradle then simply add an `application.properties` to `src/test/resources` overriding the main `application.properties`.

Comment: OK, so if I have a `src/main/resources/application.properties` (with all settings, including production db) and a  `src/main/resources/application-test.properties` (with just the H2 db settings).  When I run my tests (either from command line or inside IntelliJ) then I just need to pass in a variable indicating "test" such as `--profile=test`?  Then when I run my app, the application.properties will be used.

Comment: You shouldn't need to configure the datasources yourself, remove them and only configure the `spring.datasource.*` properties in the application.properties file of your choice. Spring Boot will take care of constructing the datasource.

Comment: I updated the question to show my current status

Comment: The fact thatyou use `db.*` as a property seems to me you are configurating the datasource yourself. As mentioned remove your datasource and just use the appropriate `spring.datasource.*` properties this will let Spring Boot create the datasource. Make sure that you override all properties (password should probably be empty for H2).

Comment: Oops, those values were not being used anywhere.  I searched the codebase and found no datasource anywhere.  I removed those entries and modified my properties file to above.

Comment: @sonoerin Please read section http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-data-access to learn how to leverage spring boot datasource support. In addition, please find a list of common spring properties in the following section  http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties you will find all the data source properties there.

Comment: @Newbie,  thank you I did read those and made changes based upon that and M. Deinums comments.  I think my application.properties files are now correct for Spring-Boot to configure my datasources, but are not being picked up correctly.

Comment: @sonoerin  The location of your  property files is important as well as activating the profiles. Make sure your command line argument is correctly activating the profile.

Comment: @Newbie, I thought it might be a problem with my gradle settings defined above.  But when I use `gradle build test -Dspring.profiles.active=test`  I still get PSQLException connection refused.  I have both applications*-properties files under `/src/main/resources` and it is apparently picking up the default.

Comment: @sonoerin Btw. the property "spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" is wrong it must be "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" Look at the [appendix a.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See section [21.3](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) of the Spring Boot documentation. This section describes how to define profile specific property files that use the format **application-{profile}.properties**. This can help you isolate properties on a per profile basis.

Comment: do we have to repeat properties in the overriding profile? i mean can we have default properties and then separate one for just the overrides; not repeating every property value?

Comment: Yes. Consider testing this yourself. Add a application.properties a long with a profile specific file.

Answer (score 10):

You can annotate your tests adding @ActiveProfiles in the following way:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class, TestSpringConfiguration.class})
@Test(groups = "integration")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyServiceTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {
...
   @Test 
   public void testSomething() {
      ...
   }
}
```

I'm using TestNG but JUnint wouldn't be much different.
You can also specify additional configuration as showed in the example above.

That way you won't need to set the profile in build.gradle or launch configuration in IntelliJ