# Spring Boot Datasource annotated with ConfigurationProperties but the properties are not loaded

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to wire datasource to get properties from application(yml) file but the Datasourcebuilder is not reading those properties. I referred [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25370696/spring-boot-datasource-profiles-w-application-properties) as well as [Spring Boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources) but could not see anything missing in my code. 
I am pasting the code below that uses Spring Boot 1.4.3.RELEASE

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan

public class MyApplication {
@Bean(name="dmDs")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public  DataSource dmDataSource(){
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
@Bean
public String aBean(){
    DataSource ds = dmDataSource(); // creates a datasource with URL, username and password empty.
    return new String("");
}
```

The application config file is as shown below:

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
  profiles:
    active: test
---

spring:
    profiles: test
    datasource:
          url: jdbc:oracle:thin:SOME_URL
          driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
          password: test
          username: test
datacollector:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@SOME_URL
    username: user
    password: pass
```

I see in the logs that the properties are read from the application.yml file

```
[main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.datasource.url' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]] with type [String]              
[main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.datasource.driver-class-name' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]] with type [String]
[main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.datasource.password' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]] with type [String]         
[main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.datasource.username' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]] with type [String]         
   JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'cipDs', 'dmDs' (OnBeanCondition)
```

I am running the application as shown below:

public static void main(String[] args){

```
SpringApplication.run(new Object[]{DecisionManagementApplication.class,ApplicationConfig.class}, args);
```

}

Comment: Why? You are using the default properties to create a datasource. That is already done by Spring Boot. So why do you need this added complexity?

Comment: I do not want the default but since my prefixes didn't work, tried tthis to test. I found from the logs that the boot is expecting a 'primary'. I even tried adding that (as updated in my question) but same issue

Comment: There needs to be a `@Primary` datasource to have it auto wired into the related other classes (health checking, `JdbcTemplate` etc). But if you need a single datasource there is no really need to add this complexity.... Also how are you testing this?

Comment: @m-deinum, I have updated the question based on your comments. I tried removing the 'configurationproperties' annotation as well as by adding 'primary'

Comment: If you have a single datasource you don't need to configure the datasource.. So if you remove those annotations things will break.

Comment: Where is this file located in your project? It should be in src/main/resources. Try adding `/` before file name. If it does not work, try removing `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation and put your configuration into src/main/resources/application.properties - check if it works.

Comment: Profile in your spring.datasource is `test` and you don't seem to run your app with this profile.

Comment: @pbielicki, yes it is in main/resources - the active profile is 'test' - updated the question by pasting the yml content. tried running by adding locations to ConfigurationProperties.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I have disabled the auto configuration as my intent is to use non-default datasources. the updated yml is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the bean Spring has created within its container you need to inject it, you can not use "new".

Try:

```java
@Bean
@Autowired
public String aBean(final DataSource  myDS)
{
    return new String("Check myDS properties now");
}
```

Comment: This worked thanks! Sorry I still do not understand how this is different from (Further Information Java Config)[http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-further-information-java-config]. Is it because the class is not annotated @Configuration that it is missing 'CGLIB magic' as explained in the above link? Thanks

Comment: That section is talking specifically about configuration classes. In that case, classes annotated with \@Configuration are subclassed at startup-time with CGLIB, so that before creating a \@Bean Spring checks first the container looking for an already existing instance for the scope. Take a look to **"Full \@Configuration vs 'lite' \@Beans mode?"** at the same documentation page: _"Only using \@Bean methods within \@Configuration classes is a recommended approach [..] This will prevent the same \@Bean method from accidentally being invoked multiple times and helps to reduce subtle bugs [...]"_